# F# FAKE WixHelper use fileFilter

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Looking at the WixHelper for F# documentation it looks like I can pass in a -filter parameter. I am still learning F# and I can't figure out how this method is supposed to work.

https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/WiXHelper.fs#L60-60

#### METHOD

wixDir fileFilter asSubDir directoryInfo

I am trying to adapt this call to filter out *.exe (I do not want to include them).

```
 wixDir (fun file -> true) true (DirectoryInfo (buildDir @@ "/SetupFiles"))
```

Comment: you just need to change `(fun file -> true)` to only return true when the file doesn't end with ".exe"

Comment: using regex? some fileInfo class? but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `(fun file -> true)` to only return true when the file doesn't end with ".exe" I assume `file` is a [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx), so you would check if the file extension is "exe".  I haven't tested this, but it should be something like this:

```
(fun file -> not (file.Extension = ".exe"))
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work but now that I look at it again I wonder if file.extension can handle filenames with periods as spaces? The exe files are still being added but their names contain periods for spaces.

Comment: Just tried using File.Name and explicitly used one of the executable's name and it worked. but I need multiple exe files filter. so would regex or another approach work?

Comment: @devfunkd Could you just compare with the end of the file name?  Like `file.Name.Substring(file.Length - 3) = "exe"`?

Comment: Actually `.Extension` includes the dot, so I think `not (file.Extension = ".exe")` should work.